# NodeJS reverse SSH tunnel: unable to bind to serveo.net:80

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh2

### Context

Not long ago, I discovered a great service called [Serveo](https://serveo.net). It allows me to expose my local apps to the Internet using reverse SSH tunneling.

e.g. Connections to `https://abc.serveo.net` get forwarded to `http://localhost:3000` on my machine.

To do this, they require no client installation, and I can just type this in the command line:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net
```

where `80` is the remote port on serveo.net to which I want to bind, and `localhost:3000` is the local address for my app.

If I just type `80` on the left-hand side, Serveo will answer `Forwarding HTTP traffic from https://xxxx.serveo.net` where `xxxx` is an available subdomain, with https support.

However, if I type another port, like `59000`, the app will be available through `serveo.net:59000`, but without SSL.

### Problem

Now, I would like to do this with NodeJS, to automate things in a tool I'm building for my coworkers and my company's partners, so that they don't need to worry about it, nor to have an SSH client on their machine. I'm using the [SSH2 Node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2).

Here is an example of working code, using the custom port configuration (here, `59000`), with an app listening on `http://localhost:3000`:

```
/**
 * Want to try it out?
 * Go to https://github.com/blex41/demo-ssh2-tunnel
 */
const Client = require("ssh2").Client; // To communicate with Serveo
const Socket = require("net").Socket; // To accept forwarded connections (native module)

// Create an SSH client
const conn = new Client();
// Config, just like the second example in my question
const config = {
  remoteHost: "",
  remotePort: 59000,
  localHost: "localhost",
  localPort: 3000
};

conn
  .on("ready", () => {
    // When the connection is ready
    console.log("Connection ready");
    // Start an interactive shell session
    conn.shell((err, stream) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // And display the shell output (so I can see how Serveo responds)
      stream.on("data", data => {
        console.log("SHELL OUTPUT: " + data);
      });
    });
    // Request port forwarding from the remote server
    conn.forwardIn(config.remoteHost, config.remotePort, (err, port) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      conn.emit("forward-in", port);
    });
  })
  // ===== Note: this part is irrelevant to my problem, but here for the demo to work
  .on("tcp connection", (info, accept, reject) => {
    console.log("Incoming TCP connection", JSON.stringify(info));
    let remote;
    const srcSocket = new Socket();
    srcSocket
      .on("error", err => {
        if (remote === undefined) reject();
        else remote.end();
      })
      .connect(config.localPort, config.localPort, () => {
        remote = accept()
          .on("close", () => {
            console.log("TCP :: CLOSED");
          })
          .on("data", data => {
            console.log(
              "TCP :: DATA: " +
              data
              .toString()
              .split(/\n/g)
              .slice(0, 2)
              .join("\n")
            );
          });
        console.log("Accept remote connection");
        srcSocket.pipe(remote).pipe(srcSocket);
      });
  })
  // ===== End Note
  // Connect to Serveo
  .connect({
    host: "serveo.net",
    username: "johndoe",
    tryKeyboard: true
  });

// Just for the demo, create a server listening on port 3000
// Accessible both on:
// http://localhost:3000
// https://serveo.net:59000
const http = require("http"); // native module
http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain"
    });
    res.write("Hello world!");
    res.end();
  })
  .listen(config.localPort);
```

This works fine, I can access my app on `http://serveo.net:59000`. But it does not support HTTPS, which is one of my requirements. If I want HTTPS, I need to set the port to `80`, and leave the remote host blank just like the plain SSH command given above, so that Servo assigns me an available subdomain:

```
// equivalent to `ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 serveo.net`
const config = {
  remoteHost: "",
  remotePort: 80,
  localHost: "localhost",
  localPort: 3000
};
```

However, this is throwing an error:

```
Error: Unable to bind to :80
at C:\workspace\demo-ssh2-tunnel\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:939:21
at SSH2Stream.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\demo-ssh2-tunnel\node_modules\ssh2\lib\client.js:628:24)
at SSH2Stream.emit (events.js:182:13)
at parsePacket (C:\workspace\demo-ssh2-tunnel\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:3851:10)
at SSH2Stream._transform (C:\workspace\demo-ssh2-tunnel\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:693:13)
at SSH2Stream.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:190:10)
at SSH2Stream._read (C:\workspace\demo-ssh2-tunnel\node_modules\ssh2-streams\lib\ssh.js:252:15)
at SSH2Stream.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:178:12)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:410:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:394:5)
```

I've tried many things without any success. If anyone has an idea about what might be wrong in my example, I'll be really grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenSSH defaults to "localhost" for the remote host when it's not specified](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/03e92dd27d491fe6d1a54e7b2f44ef1b0a916e52/channels.c#L3825-L3826). You can also verify this by checking the debug output from the OpenSSH client by adding `-vvv` to the command line. You should see a line like:

```
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:80 forwarded to local address localhost:3000
```

If you mimic this by setting `config.remoteHost = 'localhost'` in your JS code you should get the same result as the OpenSSH client.

Comment: Thank you @mscdex, that was it! I tried other values here, but never `localhost`, I guess. You saved my day